# Vue <script setup> reactivity not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Im trying the `<script setup>` syntax in vue and wondering why [reactivity](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#reactivity) is not working. What's wrong here?

```js
<template>
    <button @click="changeButtonText">{{ buttonText }}</button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

let buttonText = ref("Foo")

function changeButtonText() {
    buttonText = "Bar"
}
</script>
```

Tried without ref().
Tried with `buttonText = ref("Bar")`. No effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function you have to change
`buttonText = "Bar`" to `buttonText.value="Bar"`

For more info on reactivity see: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: Oh ok. That's it! Thank you! The example in the docs for reactivity is not the best …

Comment: @vriic could you link the bad example in the docs, please? Perhaps you should do it inside the question, to make it more helpful?

Comment: @vriic you also don't have to look straight to the example. The details state : 

The ref object is mutable - i.e. you can assign new values to .value. It is also reactive ...

Which was the thing you were looking for

Comment: I'd say naming them "Details" is a deterrent. Nobody bothers with the details anymore.

Comment: @tao https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#reactivity this example with count++

Comment: @vriic, `.value` is not necessary in template. All refs are unwrapped in template. You only need it inside `<script>`. And there's a `reactive()` wrapper which only works with objects (not primitives), which doesn't need `.value` at all. A lot of people prefer that syntax, so they don't have to deal with `.value`.

Comment: no doubt on that, but in my opinion the most reactivity happens in methods inside script and not directly in the template. so for me the count++ is a bad example ‍♂️